# How to receive guidance from your deity?

Tags: vedas, shiva, krishna, yoga, meditation

I want to know how you're supposed to receive any guidance from your deity when you don't know what to meditate on or chant any mantra/strota of that deity or something else ?

Comment: Best way is to read Stotras of your favorite deity as many times as you can by sitting in the same place/room everyday (facing East or North). After few days you will realise that your devotion for the deity has increased and gradually it will be difficult for you to pass a day without reading Stotra. Stotras for your favorite deity can be picked up from Hindupedia/Stotras.

Comment: If you feel like, maybe try listening bhajans, also looking up religious stories & imagery online, statues, art; these help me lots 

Comment: @Rickross it's so difficult for me to read even one line of stotra

Comment: @devibhakt already tried that

Comment: Gotcha. I think maybe my advice would be just keep going with it, as much as you can ? I’ve heard very often that just to keep trying, don’t let go, keep doing small stuffs towards bhakti marg whenever you can. Then slowly gradually over time the religious sentiment in you will get more strong, over months and years. This seems to be how it’s going for me, to be honest, very very slow and gradual. I think patience is key, just try be patient and let it happen naturally. This is easier said than done but I think it def happens, and in a wonderful way too, hang in there 

Comment: Then it's a problem .. unless we put in some efforts we should not expect any improvements or results ... even Lord Brahma needs to do Tapasya before creating. So effort is always necessary. @AbhinavRaj

Comment: Pray with a yearning heart.

Comment: Great advice from from Swami Vishwananda & Rickross. I think it can take a while but you’ll eventually find the answers if you keep looking 

Comment: @Rickross I'm chanting shastranaam everyday